# making firefox extension toolbar element aligned to the right

Tags: html, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

so I have this code:

```
   <toolbox id="navigator-toolbox">
      <toolbar id="abar" accesskey="T"
              class="chromeclass-toolbar" context="toolbar-context-menu"
              hidden="false" persist="hidden">
        <toolbarbutton id="ahah-b"
            label="hahaa" class="toolbarbutton-1 chromeclass-toolbar-additional custombutton" />
         <textbox id="search" />
         <toolbarbutton id="search-b" label="Search" oncommand="search()" />
      </toolbar>
   </toolbox>
```

but with this code everything gets aligned left in the toolbar. Is it possible to have the "ahah-b" toolbarbutton aligned left and yet the "search" textbox and "search-b" button aligned right?

Comment: :This will be very simple if you use flex attribute element & box element. <https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Element_Positioning>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `align='end'` to the `toolbar` should work. see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/align

Answer (score 1):

If you are still looking for an answer, the attribute you want is not align, it is pack.
[Mozilla Dev Network Docs - Pack](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/Attribute/pack)

Example from a mini site-specific browser I am working on:

```
<toolbar id="nav-toolbar" pack='end'>
  <toolbarbutton image="images/back.png" />
  <toolbarbutton image="images/next.png" />
</toolbar>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebwVY.png)